# Sticky header/item in recyclerview

Tags: android, list, view, header, sticky

I have successfully implemented sections in a recycler view as shown in the screenshot with two different types of views.
How do i implement a sticky header in the recycler view.
I want the 'A' to stick to the top until the user scrolls upwards in which case the next item to stick to the top would be 'B'.
How do i do this?

[image: Recycler View]

Comment: GitHub already has few implementations of sticky header. For example https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Comment: i would like to do it by myself so if you could point out the classes that i need to look at in the github project,that would be great or give a brief idea of how it needs to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make sticky headers in RecyclerView? (Without external lib)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib)

Answer (score 2):

**You will definitely want to use a library for this.** Emil Sjölander's [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) is a good choice (I've used it in several projects), but there are also other libraries out there.

Not knowing the specifics of your code, here's a rough sketch of how you would do it with **StickyListHeaders**:

- Create a layout for your items and headers (you probably already have that).  Let's assume these are called `item_cheese.xml` and `item_header.xml`.
- Replace your `ListView` with a `StickyListHeadersListView` in your layout file.
- Create a custom Adapter for your collection of cheeses (you probably already have that) and make it implement `StickyListHeadersAdapter`.

The interface adds only two methods:

```
public interface StickyListHeadersAdapter extends ListAdapter {
    View getHeaderView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent);
    long getHeaderId(int position);
}
```

The full implementation of your adapter would look as follows. It is using `ViewHolders` for both the items and the headers (to recycle views, like you asked):

```
public class CheeseAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

    private List<String> cheeses;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CheeseAdapter(Context context, List<String> cheeses) {
        // Assuming cheeses are already alphabetically sorted at this point
        this.cheeses = cheeses;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (cheeses != null) ? cheeses.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cheeses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheeseViewHolder holder;
        if (view != null)
            holder = (CheeseViewHolder) view.getTag();
        else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cheese, parent, false);
            holder = new CheeseViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder.decorate(cheeses.get(position));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        // Return the first char of each item as its header ID
        return cheeses.get(position).charAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        if (view != null)
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) view.getTag();
        else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder.decorate(cheeses.get(position));
        return view;
    }

    public class CheeseViewHolder {

        TextView tvCheeseName;

        public CheeseViewHolder(View view) {
            tvCheeseName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCheeseName);
        }

        public void decorate(String cheeseName) {
            if (cheeseName == null) return;
            tvCheeseName.setText(cheeseName);
        }
    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder {

        TextView tvHeader;

        public CheeseViewHolder(View view) {
            tvHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        }

        public void decorate(String cheeseName) {
            if (cheeseName == null || cheeseName.isEmpty()) return;
            tvHeader.setText(cheeseName.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
        }
    }
}
```

- Use the custom adapter in your Activity or Fragment. The ScrollView will have alphabetic sections with sticky headers and will behave [just as advertised](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders#stickylistheaders).

Simple as that.