# Flutter Widget Composition - Nested Listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Here] 
This is how I have composed a tab called Reports in flutter. It has a filter (first row in the figure) and a FutureBuilder(which returns a table). The nested Listview is custom table, and I want the table to scroll keeping the filters fixed.

Comment: Closing this in favour of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606995/flutter-implement-sticky-headers-and-the-snap-to-item-effect

Answer (score 1):

In the nested ListView add the option `shrinkWrap: true`. 
To remove the scroll effect add also `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()`

Comment: I tried that it makes the whole tab scrollable along with the headers row. Also I think that ClampingScrollPhysics is a default in android.

Comment: Oh, you want sticky headers of some sort then. I think there is a package for that.

Comment: I will check the package.