# Flutter sticky header with search bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sticky, flutter-animation

I want to implement sticky header with search TextField. The header title should be animated max to min font size(like tween animation) while scroll and search box should be stick below the header title on scroll.
[I tried this as well but not got as I expected.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliverappbar-snap-those-headers-544e097248c0)
This what I [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845924/7498057) but implementation is not explained properly. Does anyone know how to make this kind of list? It would be great if you can help me.
[image]

Comment: did you tried for [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers)?

Comment: @Sagar Stackapp This is sticky header listview. It sticks all headers whereas I want to stick header with search box.

Comment: can you please share image of your expected result?

Comment: @SagarStackapp I have updated. Please check.

Comment: Check out this code example: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below example code

[image]

```
class AnimatedAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedAppBarState createState() => _AnimatedAppBarState();
}

class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<AnimatedAppBar> {
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                toolbarHeight: 90.0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.0,
                leadingWidth: 0.0,
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                        innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Search",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              autovalidateMode:
                                  AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              /* autovalidate is disabled */
                              controller: stateController,
                              inputFormatters: [
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                    RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                    r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                              ],
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              maxLength: 160,
                              onChanged: (val) {},
                              maxLines: 1,
                              validator: (value) {},
                              focusNode: stateFocus,
                              autofocus: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                errorMaxLines: 3,
                                counterText: "",
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    )),
                                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 6.0,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                // bottom: PreferredSize(
                //   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(5.0),
                //   child: Text(''),
                // ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8.0,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Search",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/2TRIFRwcjrTuNprkTQHVxs/088159eb8e811aaac789c24701d7fdb1/LP_image.jpg?fit=fill&w=632&h=354&fm=webp"), //NetworkImage
                                    radius: 16.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                controller: stateController,
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                      RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                ],
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 160,
                                onChanged: (val) {},
                                maxLines: 1,
                                validator: (value) {},
                                focusNode: stateFocus,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                                  counterText: "",
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In addition we can also add animation

```
class AnimatedAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedAppBarState createState() => _AnimatedAppBarState();
}

class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<AnimatedAppBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();

  var animation;
  var controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
            if (innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
              /* Animation */
              controller = AnimationController(
                vsync: this,
                duration: Duration(
                  seconds: 1,
                ),
              );
              animation = Tween(
                begin: 0.0,
                end: 1.0,
              ).animate(controller);
              /* Animation */
              controller.forward();
            }
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                toolbarHeight: 90.0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.0,
                leadingWidth: 0.0,
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                        innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                      FadeTransition(
                        opacity: animation,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Search",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                controller: stateController,
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                      RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                ],
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 160,
                                onChanged: (val) {},
                                maxLines: 1,
                                validator: (value) {},
                                focusNode: stateFocus,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                                  counterText: "",
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 6.0,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                // bottom: PreferredSize(
                //   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(5.0),
                //   child: Text(''),
                // ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8.0,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Search",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/2TRIFRwcjrTuNprkTQHVxs/088159eb8e811aaac789c24701d7fdb1/LP_image.jpg?fit=fill&w=632&h=354&fm=webp"), //NetworkImage
                                    radius: 16.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                controller: stateController,
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                      RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                ],
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 160,
                                onChanged: (val) {},
                                maxLines: 1,
                                validator: (value) {},
                                focusNode: stateFocus,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                                  counterText: "",
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tejsaswini Dev. But on first scroll the header and search box is not showing.

Comment: Please try reducing animation duration

Comment: I tried with milliseconds but facing the same issue on first scroll after that it's working as expected.

Comment: Please try again. I am not facing such issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack to complete the task.

Try my solution:

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Demo',
    home: MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;
  bool showHeader = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        double scrollOffset = scrollController.offset;
        if (scrollOffset > 150) {
          if (!showHeader) {
            setState(() {
              showHeader = true;
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (showHeader) {
            setState(() {
              showHeader = false;
            });
          }
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            controller: scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.red,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  '$index',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          if (showHeader)
            Container(
              height: 150,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'Fake SearchBar',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result:
[image]

You can add your own alpha/resize animation by the way, hope it can help :)