# Flutter: SliverAppBar's bottom overlapping on FlexibleSpaceBar title

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliverappbar

I want to make a notes app like

[image: this]

I have tried this code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            stretch: true,
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: padding),
              centerTitle: false,
              title: Text(
                'Notes',
                style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle,
              ),
            ),

            // title scale and stretch effect not working when bottom is non-null
            bottom: const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
              child: MySearchBar(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding),
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: const [
            NotesItem(),
            NotesItem(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MySearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySearchBar({Key? key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 40.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(padding, 0.0, padding, 8.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: darkGrey,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black54),
            SizedBox(width: padding),
            Text(
              'Search notes',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I got output.

[image: this]

My problem is that the bottom `MySearchBar` is overlapping on `FlexibleSpaceBar` title. And also the *title scale effect* on scroll down and *stretch effect* on scroll up not working.

How do I achieve effects like the first shown video? Thank you.

Comment: you should check this,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618537/15408143