# How to prevent a child of a RecyclerView cell from moving while the user scrolls

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have very long width cells on my **horizontal** `RecyclerView`,
and I want them to have a header that remains still as the user scrolls horizontally.

```
- Recycler View (A)
-   -   Cell (parent) (B)
-   -   -   Header (C) <-- We want that to be still
-   -   -   Content (D)
```

Here's what it looks like visually:

[image]

Thus, I'm looking for a way to either:

1) Stop **the header** (C) from changing positions while the user is dragging their finger on the `RecyclerView` (A)

or

2) Scroll the cell (B) like normal, but **change the position of it's child (C) to the opposite direction**, in order to make the header **appear still** even though it is moving (in the opposite direction of the parent (B).

Here's what I'm trying to build:

[image]

Any ideas?

p.s 1: I noticed many SO answers, suggest the use of `ItemDecoration`, but all of the possible answers have code for `VERTICAL` implementations, which are very different from the `HORIZONTAL` implementations.

p.s 2 I'm creating all my view content programmatically so I won't be using layout files. (That's because the content is going to be react-native views, and I can't create those with layout files).

p.s 3: I also noticed that `ItemDecoration` is old tactic, and more recent 3rd party libraries extend the `LayoutManager`.

Please shed some light, thank you.

Comment: I'm using this answer as solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327350/4643073 Works great!

Comment: That looks promising, thanks man. Can you elaborate a bit more about how I can use this on my Horizontal implementation?

I updated my answer to provide more info.

Thanks @Tuby

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing (thanks to the inspiration Cheticamp gave me) is the following:

```
- Helper Header (C) <-- We now have an extra title view
- Recycler View (A)
-   -   Cell (parent) (B)
-   -   -   Header (C) <-- Plus the typical titles within our cells
-   -   -   Content
```

As you can see:

- We now have a helper Header view that lives outside our RecyclerView
- The Header views that live within our RecyclerView keep on moving, but right above them we place the helper view

Here's some actual code to see what happens:

public class CalendarView extends LinearLayout {
    protected LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected HeaderView helperHeaderView;
    protected RecyclerView recyclerView;

```
public CalendarView(final ReactContext context) {
    super(context);


    setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    helperHeaderView = new HeaderView(context);
    addView(helperHeaderView);




    final DailyViewAdapter adapter = new DailyViewAdapter(context) {
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

            // if our header is not assinged any position yet (we haven't given it any data yet)
            if (helperHeaderView.getLastPosition() == null) {
                updateHeaderData(helperHeaderView, globals.getInitialPosition()); // hydrate it
            }
        }
    };

    recyclerView = new SPRecyclerView(context) {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (mLayoutManager == null) {
                mLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();
            }

            // the width of any header
            int headerWidth = helperHeaderView.getWidth();

            // get the position of the first visible header in the recyclerview
            int firstVisiblePos = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            // get a ref of the Cell that contains that header
            DayView firstView = (DayView) mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisiblePos);

            // get the X coordinate of the first visible header
            float firstViewX = firstView.getX();



            // get the position of the last visible header in the recyclerview
            int lastVisiblePos = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            // get a ref of the Cell that contains that header
            DayView lastView = (DayView) mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisiblePos);

            // get the X coordinate of the last visible header
            float lastViewX = lastView.getX();


            // if the first visible position is not the one our header is set to
            if (helperHeaderView.getLastPosition() != firstVisiblePos) {
                // update the header data
                adapter.updateHeaderData(helperHeaderView, firstVisiblePos);
            }

            // if the first visible is not also the last visible (happens when there's only one Cell on screen)
            if (firstVisiblePos == lastVisiblePos) {
                // reset the X coordinates
                helperHeaderView.setX(0);
            } else { // else if there are more than one cells on screen
                // set the X of the helper header, to whatever the last visible header X was, minus the width of the header
                helperHeaderView.setX(lastViewX - headerWidth);
            }

        }
    };


    // ...
```

- All that is left to do now, turn the parent layout to a `RelativeLayout` in order to make the actual views overlap (the helper header view goes right above the recycler view).
- Also you might want to experiment with setting the helper view alpha to zero whenever needed, to make sure it looks good

I hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Although it may be possible to leave the title view within the `RecyclerView` and make it static, I suggest an alternate approach.

The title can continue to be represented internally within the `RecyclerView`, but the display will be taken outside to the top of the `RecyclerView` as follows:

```
- Title (C) <-- We want that to be still
- Recycler View (A)
-   -   Cell (parent) (B)
-   -   -   Content
```

A `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` will listen for the appearance of new items and change the title accordingly. In this way, as new items appear, the title which is a `TextView` will display the new title. The following demonstrates this.

[image]

(This is a bare-bones implementation for demonstration purposes. A full app would display the dog breed images and some sort of meaningful description.)

Here is the code that accomplishes this effect:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mBreedNameTitle;
    private int mLastBreedTitlePosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> breedList = createBreedList();

        // This is where the breed title is displayed.
        mBreedNameTitle = findViewById(R.id.breedNameTitle);

        // Set up the RecyclerView.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(breedList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Add the OnScrollListener so we know when to change the breed title.
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int lastVisible = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisible == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    return;
                }
                if (lastVisible != mLastBreedTitlePosition) {
                    mBreedNameTitle.setText(mAdapter.getItems().get(lastVisible));
                    mLastBreedTitlePosition = lastVisible;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> createBreedList() {
        List<String> breedList = new ArrayList<>();
        breedList.add("Affenpinscher");
        breedList.add("Afghan Hound");
        breedList.add("Airedale Terrier");
        breedList.add("Akita");
        breedList.add("Alaskan Malamute");
        breedList.add("American Cocker Spaniel");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Miniature)");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Standard)");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Toy)");
        breedList.add("American Foxhound");
        breedList.add("American Staffordshire Terrier");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Standard)");
        return breedList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
}

class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<String> mItems;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder) holder;

        vh.mBreedImage.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image));
        vh.mBreedName = mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mBreedImage;
        private String mBreedName;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mBreedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.breedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breedNameTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Breed name" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/cont_item_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breedImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Dog breed image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/large_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/breedImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Update:** Here is another approach that sets the left padding of a `TextView` to make the header sticky. The negative x-offset of the `TextView` is taken as padding for the header to make it slide to the right within the `TextView` and stick to the left side of the screen.

Here is the result:

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> breedList = createBreedList();

        // Set up the RecyclerView.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(breedList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                // Pad the left of the breed name so it stays aligned with the left side of the display.
                int firstVisible = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                View firstView = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisible);
                firstView.findViewById(R.id.itemBreedName).setPadding((int) -firstView.getX(), 0, 0, 0);

                // Make sure the other breed name has zero padding because we may have changed it.
                int lastVisible = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                View lastView = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisible);
                lastView.findViewById(R.id.itemBreedName).setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> createBreedList() {
        List<String> breedList = new ArrayList<>();
        breedList.add("Affenpinscher");
        breedList.add("Afghan Hound");
        breedList.add("Airedale Terrier");
        breedList.add("Akita");
        breedList.add("Alaskan Malamute");
        breedList.add("American Cocker Spaniel");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Miniature)");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Standard)");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Toy)");
        breedList.add("American Foxhound");
        breedList.add("American Staffordshire Terrier");
        breedList.add("American Eskimo Dog (Standard)");
        return breedList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

}

class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<String> mItems;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder) holder;

        vh.mBreedImage.setImageDrawable(holder.itemView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image));
        vh.mBreedName.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        vh.mBreedName.setText(mItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mBreedImage;
        private TextView mBreedName;

        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mBreedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.breedImage);
            mBreedName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemBreedName);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_layout.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/cont_item_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemBreedName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Breed name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breedImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Dog breed image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemBreedName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/large_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/breedImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemBreedName" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That's beautiful, I appreciate the time you took to write this. As a matter of fact, that thought did cross my mind, but I really want the header view to slide out with the content when the user scrolls to the next/previous item.

Any ideas?

Comment: @SudoPlz Not exactly sure what you are looking to do, but I would put a horizontal `RecyclerView` on top of the `RecyclerView` you have and populate it with the titles you want. Each item of the top `RecyclerView` will be the width of the screen. When a new item comes in from the right in the bottom `RecyclerView` I would scroll the top over so its end stays aligned with the start of the new view that is sliding in. That can be done within the scroll listener I provided. You will want to prevent the user from sliding the top `RecyclerView` over via touch and just move it programmatically.

Comment: I updated my answer to include photos, to make this more clear, mind taking a look?

Also, when it comes to adding a second `RecyclerView` on top of the existing `RecyclerView` the downside is that it won't be able to scroll horizontally with exactly the same pace the user drags their finger, as we don't have fine control over the scroll change coordinates, right?

Comment: @SudoPlz I see what you are trying to do. I think that you can get the two `RecyclerView`s in sync. There is some discussion online about doing just that. [Here](https://github.com/Stoyicker/RecyclerViewSyncDemo) is one example. However, your example doesn't look like a recycler view but a card sliding over another card. I think that you need to look at `RecyclerView` item decorations and "sticky" headers. [Here](https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders) is one implementation that you may be able to adapt to your situation.

Comment: You my friend are a legend, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll study your code in more depth now.

By the way, is there any down side from doing it that way instead of using an `ItemDecoration` decorator?

Comment: @SudoPlz I think the padding way is the way to go. If you are not under a tight deadline, you may want to explore the decoration approach. It is more involved while the padding approach is easier to understand.

Comment: Is the `ItemDecoration` way more performant in any way compared to the padding approach?

Comment: @SudoPlz Not sure which is better for performance. My guess is that the padding method is more efficient but I don't think it is going to really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this library help : [TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView)

```
<com.evrencoskun.tableview.TableView
    android:id="@+id/content_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:column_header_height="@dimen/column_header_height"
    app:row_header_width="@dimen/row_header_width"
    app:selected_color="@color/selected_background_color"
    app:shadow_color="@color/shadow_background_color"
    app:unselected_color="@color/unselected_background_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this answer as solution [stackoverflow.com/a/44327350/4643073](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44327350/4643073) Works great!

If you want horizontal sticky header, just change eveything related to "verticalness", change `getY()` to `getX()`, `getTop()` to `getRight()`,
`getHeight()` to `getWidth()`.

Why do you think `ItemDecoration` is old tactic? It is not deprecated, it doesn't mess your adapter to extend some specific class, it's working well.

Comment: Well if I use a separate view type for my `Header`, and another view type for my `Content`, then the `Header` will not have the same x with my content (they won't overlap). On the vertical list that's not an issue, but if you take a look at the image above, I need the header to be right above the content. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is it too much to ask for an example?

Comment: Well, you can define your own custom sticky header layout inside example I linked, I happened to use the same as in my ViewHolder but it  is not requirement. Look at `getHeaderLayout()` method inside interface