# Make Recycler view item non-swipable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my recycler view, I need to set the header item non-swipable. I override the methods getSwipeDirs() and getMovementFlags() and returns 0 for the header position,but now also its able to swipe. What is wrong with my code.

Nb:I set my swiping to one direction only(left to right)

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.shanto.inventory.adapters.MaterialAdapter;
import com.example.shanto.inventory.adapters.MaterialDetailAdapter;



public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper_MaterialDetail extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper_MaterialDetail(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

   /* @Override
    public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        *//*if (viewHolder instanceof MaterialDetailAdapter.HeaderVH) return 0;
        return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);*//*
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        return position == 0 ? 0 : super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    }*/
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof MaterialDetailAdapter.HeaderVH){
            return makeMovementFlags(0, 0);
        } else {
            return makeMovementFlags(0, super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final View foregroundView = ((MaterialDetailAdapter.MaterialVH) viewHolder).item;

            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MaterialDetailAdapter.MaterialVH) viewHolder).item;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MaterialDetailAdapter.MaterialVH) viewHolder).item;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MaterialDetailAdapter.MaterialVH) viewHolder).item;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
        void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
    }
}
```

Here I update the code used for swiping

Comment: your coded is needed here in order to understand the problem

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib

Comment: where is your code that you have tried so far my friend? Please add code , if you want solution .

Comment: Yeah, add some code samples. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: can you please add the ScreenShot that you are Currently Getting and want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I use the below code for swiping in activity

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback1 = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                // Row is swiped from recycler view
                // remove it from adapter
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        };
```

where SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) makes the item swipe always left,that makes me confused.