# How to make different view item types with StickHeader in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, chat

I'm developing an android **chat app**. How can I make this info bar that indicates for example : "**user** left the group" or "**user** changed the group icon", like in the photo below:

**YELLOW MARKS**
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327350/1283715)

Comment: Thanks, Khaled Lela for answering. I'm already using StickHeader adapter for dates sticker in the chat, but I'm wondering if there is another way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 final Chat chat = getItem(position);
    if (chat.getType() == LEFT_CHAT) {
        return ITEM_TYPE_LEFT_CHAT;
    } else if(chat.getType() == JOIN_CHAT){
        return ITEM_TYPE_JOIN_CHAT;
    } else if(chat.getType() == CHANGE_CHAT_ICON){
        return ITEM_TYPE_CHAGE_CHAT_ICON;
    } else {
        return ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL;
    }
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL) {
        View normalView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_normal_row, null);
        return new MyNormalViewHolder(normalView); // view holder for normal items
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_LEFT_CHAT) {
        View headerRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.left_chat_row, null);
        return new MyHeaderViewHolder(headerRow); // view holder for header items
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_JOIN_CHAT) {
        View headerRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.join_chat_row, null);
        return new MyHeaderViewHolder(headerRow); // view holder for header items
    } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_CHAGE_CHAT_ICON) {
        View headerRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.change_chat_icon_row, null);
        return new MyHeaderViewHolder(headerRow); // view holder for header items
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's what I excactly need. could you please share the full code with me or at least the layouts. 
THANK YOU SO MUCH