# How to create Sticky recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I want to create Sticky recycleview with multiple headers , the header are working perfectly fine but the recyclerview doesn't make them sticky. This is my first time with Sticky recycleview headers . And also i would like to know is this the proper way of doing it.

Here is my Adapter.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private List<ItemObject> itemObjects;
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter( Context context , List<ItemObject> itemObjects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemObjects = itemObjects;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(layoutView);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(layoutView , context);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No match for " + viewType + ".");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemObject mObject = itemObjects.get(position);
        if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder){
            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).headerTitle.setText(mObject.getContents());
        }else if(holder instanceof ItemViewHolder){
            ((ItemViewHolder) holder).itemContent.setText(mObject.getContents());
        }
    }
    private ItemObject getItem(int position) {
        return itemObjects.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemObjects.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }
}
```

and here is my method in main activity.

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this , getDataSource());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   private List <ItemObject> getDataSource(){
  List<ItemObject> list1 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();

        list1.add(new ItemObject("First Header",true));
        list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));


        List <ItemObject> list2 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
        list2.add(new ItemObject("Second Header",true));
        list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));


        List <ItemObject> list3 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
        list3.add(new ItemObject("Third Header",true));
        list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));

        List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list2);
        finalList.addAll(list3);

        return finalList;
}
```

Comment: Sticky headers are really hard, so I'd just recommend using https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor library -- it worked wonders for us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make sticky headers in RecyclerView? (Without external lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib)