# ItemDecoration doesn't work inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have implemented RecyclerView with sticky headers and I did it through ItemDecoration.
It works as expected in the case of stand-alone recycler view.

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView .../>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView ... /> // ItemDecoration is supposed to be here and it works excellent
</LinearLayout>
```

But I have two lists and I need to use NestedScrollView

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView .../>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView ... /> // It doesn't work here
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
```

In this case ItemDecoration doesn't work.

I've found out next information:

- onDrawOver's are not called on scrolling because RecyclerView.draw() is not called as well.
- All items are created at same time (so Adapter creates view holders for all items in the data). It's bad, but it's not my main problem.
- I tried to force calling recyclerview's redraw on scrolling but it doesn't work

Do you have any advice how to fix it?

UPD xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_background_color"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/menuNewsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Code initialization:

```
listMenu.apply {
    adapter = dishAdapter
    isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
listMenu.addItemDecoration(HeaderItemDecoration(listMenu, isHeader = isHeader()))
```

HeaderItemDecoration was copied from there
[How can I make sticky headers in RecyclerView? (Without external lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib)

Comment: Can you clear one thing, by "ItemDecoration doesn't work" do you mean the decoration headers don't render or it does but doesn't scroll as required.

Comment: ItemDecoration doesn't render. Actually onDrawOver's are even not called

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Stuck with the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add an `ItemDecoration` to a `RecyclerView` using the `addDecoration(ItemDecoration decoration)` method?

Comment: I've added. In the first described case it works well.

Comment: Does the ItemDecoration work for the first RecyclerView, even if it's not actually supposed to be there? Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you provide more details such as the attributes of the views and view group? I would have tried to replicate the problem but it's more difficult to that without more contextual information?

Comment: First RecyclerView has a horizontal scrolling, so ItemDecoration won't work with it. But if move 2nd RecyclerView to the top it won't work as well. Also if remove NestedScrollView it works as expected

Comment: I've added more details to the my main question

Comment: did you fix this one, I am facing the same issue