# Stick TabLayout on top of screen

Tags: android

I have a layout that contains a tree of views like below:

```
    - ConstraintLayout
     -- TextView
    - WebView
    - TabLayout (1) (3 tabs)
    - ViewPager (1)
    - TabLayout (2) (4 tabs)
    - ViewPager (2)
```

When user scrolls to `ViewPager (1)`, `TabLayout (1)` will stick at top and able to interact like below GIF in Huobi app. And if user scrolls more to `ViewPager (2)`, it will push `TabLayout (1)` out and `TabLayout (2)` will be sticked on top.

I tried some articles like (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327350 -- It creates fake view and not able to interact header) and libs like (https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems -- quite too long no update) but i don't feel it good.

Any good practice on this? I see many apps used it but not sure will Google supports it natively and not sure what I missed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

Update 13/12/2021

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color">

        // Header 
        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout_header"
            layout="@layout/layout_header" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/wvChart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/webview_height" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tl1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tablayout_height"
                    style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/wvChart"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle"/>

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/vpg1"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/viewpager_market_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/background_color"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tl1"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tl2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tablayout_height"
                    style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/vpg1"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle"/>

                <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                    android:id="@+id/vpg2"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/viewpager_market_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/background_color"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tl2"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I am currently using this lib [StickyScrollView](https://github.com/amarjain07/StickyScrollView), it works as expected but contains minor bugs. I still want to find other stable way. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer helped you? :)

Answer (score 1):

As I had no source code from you, I just started to make an own little project to achieve that. First of all you need to take a `CoordinatorLayout` as base frame. In that you use an `AppBarLayout` that is the parent of a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and in that you can put your content (here e.g. `TextView`). The second `Toolbar` in it needs to be pinned (`app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`)
Below that you will continue with the `NestedScrollView` to have no glitches etc., for a smooth UX.

There you go with your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#6200EA"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Collapsing Toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:text="Trade your Bitcoins here:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Collapsed Toolbar:**

[image: collapsed]

**Extended Toolbar:**

[image: extended]

---

I think now you should have a good inspiration how to design further. It's the same principal. In terms of time I just made a ruff version. In your shown GIF it's just an additional `Toolbar` at the top, that's normally known as "`DarkActionbar`" in `themes.xml`. And the `RecyclerView`  (in your example "Order Book") will be added as a child in `NestedScrollView`. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your idea. It seems does not fit my requirements. As I understand, It only support 1 header. I updated the layout structure on question. If I am wrong, please help me on that layout. Thanks.