# RecyclerView.ItemDecoration Text Accessibility

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility

The most common way to to create a "Header" in a `RecyclerView` is by implementing `ItemDecoration`.

The header usually involves some text of course. We create a "Header View" layout, inflate it and then draw to the canvas. A bit like in an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665611/316825).

But the problem with this very common approach is that the header text is then not part of the view tree and therefore is **not accessible** (Cannot be read out by TalkBack etc)

How have people got around this? Can someone point me to an example of an `ItemDecoration` being implemented that is **compatible with accessibility?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like what is done here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/get-ahead-using-headers-in-recyclerview-2909a69b19?