# Sticky scroll view for Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, scrollview, sticky

I want to implement a sticky scroll view inside my layout in a way that when one specific type of view (inside the scroll view) is encountered then it gets stick at the top until the other similar type of view is encountered.

I found this library but it's pretty old, if you know any new one please let me know.
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

Also I am using static data inside my scroll view.
I have attached screenshots to show what I want to achieve
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib)

Comment: @SanoopSurendran I went through this but it's a lot of Java code and I am working with Kotlin as a beginner, is it possible to implement it using just the xml ? Also currently I am using just static data inside scroll view so there is no use of adapters and recycler view

Comment: If am not wrong, there are a plenty of open source github libraries available, pls check [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sticky+header+recyclerview+android+github&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN918IN918&oq=Stickyheader+android+re&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i13j0i22i30l7j0i8i13i30.10366j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)