# Sticky item in Android's RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a recyclerView with multiple viewTypes, is there any way using which I can stick a particular viewType on top of the recyclerView once it reaches there after getting scrolled up?
This viewHolder initially appears at the bottom but once user scrolls up and the view reaches on top I want it to stick there and on scroll down naturally comes down to original position.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949971/how-can-i-make-sticky-headers-in-recyclerview-without-external-lib